# How to automatically show task pane for non-function add-in when opening worksheet?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

How can we tell Excel (Web and Desktop) to *load* but not *show* an add-in automatically when a workbook is opened? We want code in the add-in to check the worksheet and, if our add-in has been used on it, open the add-in task pane automatically (though we'll give the user an opt-out of the behavior).

(The add-in is just a task pane, not custom functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already done that, I would recommed taking a look at the options for [running code in your Office add-in when the document opens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/run-code-on-document-open). From that page:

> **Configure your add-in to load when the document opens**
>
> The following code configures your add-in to load and start running when the document is opened.
>
> ```js
> Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Place startup code in `Office.initialize`**
>
> When your add-in is configured to load on document open, it will run immediately. The `Office.initialize` event handler will be called. Place your startup code in the `Office.initialize` or `Office.onReady` event handler.